# What happens to non-domain controller workstations/servers when user rights assignment policies are removed/no longer apply?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I'm trying to do a good ol' fashioned Group Policy Object clean-up job on our domain controller that was upgraded from Windows 2000 (Small Business I think) to Windows Server 2008R2.

In my company's domain we have a `Default Domain Controllers Policy` that has been linked to the entire domain. This GPO contains mostly `Local Policies/User Rights Assignment`policies that I want to set as closely to the [defaults](http://theintegrity.co.uk/2011/05/windows-server-2008-r2-domain-controller-default-domain-policy-default-settings/) as possible.

What happens to the workstations/servers *User Rights Assignments* when I unlink the GPO from the entire domain and let it only apply to the Domain Controllers OU?

Do the workstations revert to their default behaviour or do I need to make a GPO to assign the workstations/servers their defaults?

Bonus Question: Is there a definitive resource, rule or list of Group Policy settings that will effectively reset to whatever the `Undefined` behaviour is on the computer or is that something where every setting is unique and must be researched on an individual basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experience of *removing* items from AD, group policy continues to apply and settings do *not* revert.  Since there was an policy disabling the local administrator account in group policy, this caused no end of vexation at $former_employer.

I cannot, of course, speak to every item you might have defined via group policy.  You might want to apply/unapply to a test item and see what happens.

Bonus question:  Not official, but see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/560736/revert-gpo-settings-to-undefined).