# How to repeal a Security Setting GPO and revert the machine back to defaults?

Tags: windows, group-policy

So [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/560736/revert-gpo-settings-to-undefined) asks whether its possible to revert/undo settings previously configured by Group Policy. As explained in the [great answer](https://serverfault.com/a/560911/88679), because of "tattooing", the change will be made and there is no way to know or revert to anything else.

However, I don't need to revert, I need to go back to defaults. In some cases, GPOs will do exactly that when using "Disabled" or "Not configured" but in other cases, such as in the `Windows Settings\Security Settings` area, you "define" or "not define". Define "tattoos" a setting, and enforces it. Not defining it, simply removes the enforcement.

How can you revert security settings back to defaults? Can you simply delete the related registry key as a one-time task GPP? Is that at all recommended for something as important as security policies?

Context: I've inherited a terrible mess of Group Policies. Some of which are pushing horribly insecure security policies that I wish to simply remove and allow Windows to default, rather than enforce a new setting.

Answer (score 2):

HEMAN85's link mentions this in it's list, but for simplicity and succinctness:

1. Fix your GPO, or flush out the old one if needed.
2. Open Powershell as Admin and `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`

The templates it's restoring SHOULDN'T have been messed with... unless whomever set everything up did something super wonky.  Also note this is just for security, but that's what I think you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know your purposes, but here is a few ways to do it: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-all-group-policy-settings-to-default